# How can I convert a image into a byte array in uwp platform

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need to convert an image into a byte array to store it in a database. and also I need to convert that array back to the image. I did google research but I couldn't find a solution because in `UWP` platform some api doesn't available.

Comment: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-image-in-a-windows-store-app/ ?

Comment: thank you very much. it really helped.I found this also useful http://www.evelix.ch/unternehmen/Blog/evelix/2013/01/06/Windows_8_WinRT_save_an_image_to_database_and_read_the_image_again_from_the_database.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution from these articles as [theoutlander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460472/theoutlander) says.

To convert a image into a byte[] i'm going to use the 'OpenSequentialReadAsyn()' method of a storage file.

lets assume that our image is 'file'. to convert it into a byte array do the below

```
 using (var inputStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
        {
            var readStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead();

            var byteArray =  new byte[readStream.Length];
            await readStream.ReadAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            return byteArray;
        }
```

To convert the byte[] back into a image do the following,

```
 using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
            {
                writer.WriteBytes(this.byteArray);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
            }
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            return image;

        }
```

you can find more in this [article](http://www.evelix.ch/unternehmen/Blog/evelix/2013/01/06/Windows_8_WinRT_save_an_image_to_database_and_read_the_image_again_from_the_database.aspx).

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the links which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the links goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.