# UWP - load WritableBitmap from byte array returns weird image

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, inkcanvas, writablebitmap

I have an `InkCanvas` drawing, which i convert to `WriteableBitmap` and set is as an `ImageSource` as follows:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(ms.AsOutputStream());
ms.Position = 0;
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)inkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas.ActualHeight);
wb.SetSource(ms.AsRandomAccessStream());
image.Source = wb;
```

That works fine.

Now i need to store the `WriteableBitmap` as a byte array in database in order to use it as image source of a `GridView` item. This is the method i use to convert the bitmap to byte[]:

```
using (Stream stream = ((WriteableBitmap)image.Source).PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    data = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

and this one to restore the bitmap form byte[]:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(200,200);
using (Stream stream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Now here are the screenshots describes how the image looks after retrieving from InkCanvas and after retrieving from byte[]:

[image]

Will be grateful if someone faced that issue and has a solution.

Comment: Have you taken a look [at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35111635/2681948)?

Comment: Yep, tried other methods, including those in the thread you provided. Results are different, sometimes it returns those dots, sometimes just a blank image and sometimes it throws an error.

Comment: How do you know the original bitmap was 200x200?

Comment: Raymond Chen, im so dumb, the size was incorrect. I had corrected it and it is working now! Post an answer, i will accept it.