# Content of ImageEx do not changes after source of images has been changed

Tags: uwp, binding

I get image by `FileOpenPicker` in viewmodel like this:

`FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
 StorageFile image = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();`

then I set value of `Path` property of `image` to `PathToImage` property of viewmodel that has `Uri` type (I am using `INotifyPropertyChange` realisation by Template10):

```
public Uri PathToImage
{
    set { Set(ref _pathToImage, value); }
    get { return _pathToImage; }
}
```

This is bindable property to the `Source` property of `ImageEx`:

```
<Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls:ImageEx Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.PathToImage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I expected that content of `ImageEx` will changes after I will set value to the
`PathToImage` but it do not occur. First of all I thought that it happens because of types of properties `PathToImage` and `Source` are various but I set to the `Source` path of image that is located in `Assets` folder. And image was viewed. So it is not problem in types. I have no idea where it can be error that do not let program work. So explain me please how to make `ImageEx` able to view image after `PathToImage` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pass string path to image directly. The mage is located in Assets so you need combine `ms-appx:///Assets` uri scheme with file name like the following.

```
private string _pathToImage = "ms-appx:///Assets/test.jpg";
public string PathToImage
{
    get { return _pathToImage; }
    set { Set(ref _pathToImage, value); }

}
```

**Xaml**

```
<mControl:ImageEx RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.PathToImage,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**Change the property**

```
this.ViewModel.PathToImage =  "ms-appx:///Assets/test2.jpg";
```

Comment: After user have choosed image I set image`s path to PathToImage. And I make it like you advise with "ms-appx:///" but still it is not any changes. After I add "ms-appx:///" my path become like this: {ms-appx:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/hellowithwaves.png}. One useful detail that there is no problem with binding cause I have copied URI of images from internet and pasted it in PathToImage and images was viewed in ImageEx during run time. So maybe there is other mistakes in path string?

Comment: `ms-appx:///Assets` is used to access the content that stored in the porject `Assets` folder.

Comment: You could not access  desktop image  with such path  `C:/Users/User/Desktop/hellowithwaves.png`.

Comment: Plase try get file with FilOpenPicker and set image source with file in the view model. To avoid use the path to access file in uwp.

Comment: For more detail please refer [file access permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) and uwp[uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes).

Comment: Good idea to set image source with file so I have tried to do this but did not gain success. But I have found working solution: Convert file into the byte array and then reconvert this array to image. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111635/how-can-i-convert-a-image-into-a-byte-array-in-uwp-platform).